# cut function produces uneven first break

Tags: r

I'm exploring the use of the `cut` function and am trying to cut the following basic vector into 10 breaks.  I'm able to do it, but I'm confused as to why my initial break occurs at -0.1 rather than 0:

```
test_vec <- 0:10
test_vec2 <- cut(test_vec, breaks = 10)
test_vec2
```

yields:

```
(-0.01,1] (-0.01,1] (1,2]     (2,3]     (3,4]     (4,5]     (5,6]     (6,7]     (7,8]     (8,9]    (9,10]
```

Why does this produce 2 instances of `(-0.01,1] (-0.01,1]`  and the lower number does not start at 0?

Comment: because `cut` by default does not include the lower limit. so to include `0` you must have a number slightly less than 0, ie a negative. Also, since cut by default includes the upper linit, hence `0` and `1` are in the same category. ie `(-0.01,1]` hence these two instances, where the first instance is for `0` while the second is for `1`. If you need to include the lower limit, use `include.lowest = TRUE`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**tl;dr** to get what you might want, you'll probably need to specify breaks explicitly, and `include.lowest=TRUE`:

```
cut(x,breaks=0:10,include.lowest=TRUE)
```

The issue is probably this, from the "Details" of `?cut`:

> When ‘breaks’ is specified as a single number, the range of the
>        data is divided into ‘breaks’ pieces of equal length, and then the
>        outer limits are moved away by 0.1% of the range to ensure that
>        the extreme values both fall within the break intervals.

Since the range is (0,10), the outer limits are (-0.01, 10.01); as @Onyambu suggests, the results are asymmetric because the value at 0 lies on the left-hand boundary (not included) whereas the value at 10 lies on the right-hand boundary (included).

The (apparent) asymmetry is due to formatting; if you follow the code below (the core of `base:::cut.default()`, you'll see that the top break is actually at 10.01, but gets formatted as "10" because the default number of digits is 3 ...

```
x <- 0:10
breaks <- 10
dig <- 3
nb <- as.integer(breaks+1)
dx <- diff(rx <- range(x, na.rm = TRUE))
breaks <- seq.int(rx[1L], rx[2L], length.out = nb)
breaks[c(1L, nb)] <- c(rx[1L] - dx/1000, rx[2L] +  dx/1000)
ch.br <- formatC(0 + breaks, digits = dig, width = 1L)
```